# Carousel Sharing Row - Horizontal

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make it so that my carousel can share a horizontal row with other text but it isn't working as for some reason its taking up 100% width when its set to take 40%.

I'll post code and screenshots below.

[image]

In the picture above, it shows the carousel with text under it but I want the text to be beside it.

When I use Chrome's development kit it shows that a margin is taking up the whole row on the right side but I don't believe it says that anywhere in the code D:

Code:

```
<div style="border:2px solid #cecece;margin-left:7%;margin-top:3%;margin-right:7%;padding:1%;">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide span4" data-ride="carousel" style="margin:0px !important;">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://images.eurogamer.net/2013/usgamer/league_of_legends.jpg" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            League of Legends
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://assets1.ignimgs.com/vid/thumbnails/user/2013/09/03/minecraft.jpg" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            Minecraft
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://www.gamerheadlines.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/135.jpg" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            Call of Duty: Ghosts
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
     <div class="span5">
        <p>Test</p>
     </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel{width:40% !important;}
.carousel .slide {
    width:40% !important;
}
```

Comment: Adding your CSS code would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry about that I forgot, I'll add it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `div` element will, unless instructed otherwise, appear as a block element. Unless specified otherwise, this block will fill out the entire width of the next outer container which has been supplied a width or derived one from the logical order of elements in the document.

Your outer wrapper `div` (`#carousel-example-generic`) was set to classname `.slide` (and `.carousel .slide` btw, which overlaps, so one definition does suffice), therefore a `width` of `40%` was applied through the CSS definitions. If you remove the `width`, as another user suggested, and then apply `display:inline-block` to your carousel wrapper, add a `div` right afterwards which also is set to `display:inline-block`, you end up with the two elements next to one another.

[See this fiddle for a demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhcLN/2/)

Please note: i added outer wrappers so that its clearer to you why it works and how it is achieved.

Also note that while `inline-block` is nowadays widely supported, there are a few older browsers which are still fairly present, which have problems with that CSS property.

[Refer to this page to learn more about browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block)

If you want to take a safer route you can choose to `float` the two `div` elements next to one another, but be aware that you must [clear the floats](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/clear) if you don't want any adjacent elements to appear next to your `div`.

Comment: I tried both those suggestions and they didn't work :/ But I believe I know what you mean about where the issue stems from. Any other idea how I could fix? Do you want me to make a jsFiddle of the document?

Comment: How could I get it so the text is inside the border though?

Comment: Simply apply the `border` CSS property to the outer wrapper instead.  See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhcLN/3/). Note that a `padding` will produce a space `within` the `border`, while a `margin` will produce a space outside of the `border`.

Comment: No prob! Hit an upvote to codehorse's answer - he was right about the `width` on the parent container.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is the thing causing the border and that is at 100%.

Are you able to change this div that has no ID or class?

just add width: 40% inside this div, if possible.

```
<div style="width: 40%; border:2px solid #cecece;margin-left:7%;margin-top:3%;margin-right:7%;padding:1%;">
```

Comment: Can't do that, that div is just to put a border around both elements.